# обновление версии Pandas для чтения Excel

Tags: pandas

Колаб вдруг перестал читать Excel - файлы. С 01.02.2022. Раньше все было ок.

Пишет:
ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.0.0' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '2.5.9' currently installed).

Что делать?

такое pip install pandas - не помогает...

Comment: вам как бы намекают на то, что обновлять надо `openpyxl` ;)

Comment: а как? вот так pip install xlrd xlwt openpyxl - тоже бестолку

Comment: Если так pip install openpyxl то отновляет до той же версии 2.5.9

Comment: `pip install openpyxl --upgrade` ?

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Заработало!!!